# azure ad b2c custom policy - how to get user object id and email in the claim?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

went through the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=app-reg-preview to create a custom policy to use Local account sign up/in. however the user object id and email address are missing from the token. any idea on how to get these claims?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sub` is the user object id and `signInName` is the email.

[image]

Here is the **OutputClaims**.

```
<OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />

      </OutputClaims>
```

Comment: yes, signInName is the email but if you want to it to appear as email claim, use this <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="SignInName" PartnerClaimType="email"/>